# How do I make a JTable editable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using a JTable in java, but it won't let me edit the cells.

```
private final TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {

        public int getColumnCount() { 
            return 5; 
        }

        public int getRowCount() { 
            return 10;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
            return new Integer(row*col); 
        }
};

private final JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
```

Comment: Make sure you take the time to read through [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add the follwoing code

```
 public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
      { return true; }
 public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    rowData[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
  }
```

you should have a array where you will save the changes

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 private final TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {

        public int getColumnCount() { 
            return 5; 
        }

        public int getRowCount() { 
            return 10;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
            return new Integer(row*col); 
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                    return true;
                }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `isCellEditable()` function inside the anonymous inner class `AbstractTableModel`

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) { 
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add isCellEditable() to the rows and columns you want them to be editable, example if you don't want some columns like ID to be editable return false. Keep in mind that you need to save the editit data some where

```
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) { 
       return true;  // or false for none editable columns
    }
 public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
  rowData[row][col] = value; // save edits some where
  fireTableCellUpdated(row, col); // informe any object about changes
}
```