# how edit cell in jtable and then save it to DB whit query JAVA?

Tags: java, sql, jtable, cell, editing

I want to edit a specific cell in a `JTable` and then save it in a database. I'm using SQL. I've tried out a lot of codes and I did not find anything.

This is my table,

[image: table]

I've populated with data from DB. How can I edit any cell and press enter to save it in the DB? or with a `JButton`?

I managed to do it selecting a row, do the editing with `JTextField` and save it but it's better just editing in the cell.

**EDIT:**

I'm pasting my code to help you understand my issue.

This is how I've created the table:

[image: create]

This is how I've populated the table.

[image: populate]

So, I want to edit a cell in the `JTable` and save the changes in the DB.

Comment: Since you did not include what approach are you following, question is too broad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a JTable editable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008145/how-do-i-make-a-jtable-editable-in-java)

Comment: What you meant? I have trouble to understand

Comment: Concretely, focus on `isCellEditable` method  to make your `JTable` editable and then focus on  `setValueAt` method to make the update in your DB. if you include what you are doing currently it could be easy to see what you  are missing

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Since i not have a good answer finally i came with my own! i did it!!
post the solution to my problem.
first i did this.

```
public void TableCuentas(){
     String[] columnas = {"ID","FECHA", "TIPO MATERIAL", "KILOGRAMOS" , "$ POR KILO", "DEBEMOS", "SALDO"};
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        desplazamiento = new JScrollPane();

          desplazamiento.setBounds(20, 173, 673, 277);
          frameCC.getContentPane().add(desplazamiento);
          modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(columnas);
          desplazamiento.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            desplazamiento.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);            
            frameCC.getContentPane().add(desplazamiento, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            tabla = new JTable();
            desplazamiento.setViewportView(tabla);
            tabla.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

            tabla.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
            tabla.setFillsViewportHeight(true);                     
            tabla.setModel(modelo);
            tabla.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            tabla.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
            tabla.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

           modelo.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

                    actualizatabla(e);

              }
            });
            if (tabla.getCellEditor() != null) {
              tabla.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();

            }

 }
```

and then i did this

```
protected void actualizatabla(TableModelEvent e)  {

    if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {


        modelo = (DefaultTableModel) ((TableModel) (e.getSource()));
        int fila = e.getFirstRow();
        int columna = e.getColumn();

        String dato=String.valueOf(modelo.getValueAt(tabla.getSelectedRow(),tabla.getSelectedColumn()));
        texto.setText(dato);

        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        String strCodigo = modelo.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();


        String sSQL = "";

      if (columna==1){
        sSQL =   "UPDATE materiales SET fechaIngreso=? WHERE ID=("+strCodigo+")" ;
      }
      if (columna==2){
          sSQL =   "UPDATE materiales SET tipoMat=? WHERE ID=("+strCodigo+")" ;
      }
      if (columna==3){
          sSQL =   "UPDATE materiales SET kg=? WHERE ID=("+strCodigo+")" ;
      }
      if (columna==4){
          sSQL =   "UPDATE materiales SET precio=? WHERE ID=("+strCodigo+")" ;
      }
      lblNewLabel_1.setText(String.valueOf(strCodigo));

  Connection conexion = null;


        try {
        conexion= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://SERVER:3306/material?useSSL=false","admin" ,"admin");

              PreparedStatement pstm = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sSQL);

                  pstm.execute();


        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + ex);
        }   



    }
}
```

and now i can edit a table cell and when i press enter the cell just change the value and save it direct to the DB. i hope it help someone.