# How to create dynamically text fields an labels as the number of my row in result set?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, resultset

`JFrame` is very new to me.

I am trying to create a new frame that will contain for each row in my result set a label with the name of the user and an individual text field for it.
The query should return all the users in the specific flat for example for flat 1 the frame should look like this:

[image: example]

This is the SQL table:

[image: table]

Please help me figure out how to do it.

**Update:**

I found a solution for creating it dynamically.
I decided that I want to insert the fields that creating dynamically in a panel with a scroll bar that will be inside the main panel, but I keep struggling with that.

The solution for dynamic creation:

```
public class NewBill extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane,panel = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane scrPane;
    private int x=93;
    private int y=103;
    private int myflatid;
    private JTextField noticetf;
    private JTextField amounttf;
    public NewBill(int myflatid) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.myflatid=myflatid;
        int rows=0;
        Connection con = dbConnection.instance().getConn();
        
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query ="SELECT Name, LastName FROM PayTheBills.Account WHERE Flat_id='" + myflatid + "'";
       try {
           ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
             rows++;;
        }
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
        JTextField jt[]=new JTextField[rows];
        JLabel jl[]=new JLabel[rows];
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 709, 574);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
        
        JLabel lblNotice = new JLabel("Notice:");
        lblNotice.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblNotice.setBounds(12, 45, 73, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNotice);
        
        JLabel lblAmount = new JLabel("Amount:");
        lblAmount.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblAmount.setBounds(12, 74, 73, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblAmount);
        
        noticetf = new JTextField();
        noticetf.setBounds(93, 43, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(noticetf);
        noticetf.setColumns(10);
        
        amounttf = new JTextField();
        amounttf.setColumns(10);
        amounttf.setBounds(93, 73, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(amounttf);
        
        JCheckBox cbox = new JCheckBox("Split even");
        cbox.setBounds(230, 71, 113, 25);
        contentPane.add(cbox);

        insert(rows,jt,jl,rs);
        
    }
    
    public void insert(int rows,JTextField[] jt,JLabel[] jl,ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++) {
            jt[i]=new JTextField();
            jt[i].setBounds(x, y, 116, 22);
            getContentPane().add(jt[i]);
            if(rs.next())
            jl[i]=new JLabel(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
            jl[i].setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
            jl[i].setBounds(12, y, 150, 30);
            getContentPane().add(jl[i]);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            y+=30;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is appropriate?

Comment: How I will give for each row its own text field?

Comment: [How do I make a JTable editable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008145/how-do-i-make-a-jtable-editable-in-java)

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).